# Sed: Why does [^\]] not seem to work?

Tags: regex, linux, sed

I was trying to match/output all the text before the first `]` appeared:

```
sed -i -r 's/^([^\]]*).*/\1/' "$FILE.tmp"
```

Which surprisingly does not work.

However, searching for the other bracket does work:

```
sed -i -r 's/^([^\[]*).*/\1/' "$FILE.tmp"
```

Is this a sed bug or am I doing it wrong?

I know I can work around this using `.*?` which is good enough but this issue had me stumped for long enough that I'd like to know if there is something I missed.

(According --version, I am using GNU sed 4.2.2.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to quote the closing bracket `]`. In fact your regular expression is parsed as `[^\]` followed by a stray `]`.

You want to use the following regular expression (note the lack of quoting with `\`):

```
sed -i -r 's/^([^]].*).*/\1/' "$FILE.tmp"
```

The second regular expression works by chance because `[` has no special meaning in a `[]` expression but you'll find that it also match lines that start by a `\`.

In fact, when using `]` in a `[]` group, it must be the first character, or the second if the first one is a `^`.

Answer (score 2):

It should be:

```
sed -r 's/^([^]]+).*/\1/'
```

Note that you don't need to quote the `]` if it appears in a character group.

Comment: ...and it has to be the first character in the character group, or it closes the group.

Comment: Wait, you are right... Why don't I need to escape this?

Comment: @nulldozer: you can escape it in a PCRE regex. POSIX forbids it. To match  `]` and `-`, you need to use "smart" placement. See another answer.