# How to escape closing square bracket within regular expression character class?

Tags: regex, sed, escaping, character-class

This command works as expected:

```sh
$ echo "foo}bar]baz" | sed 's/}/@/g; s/]/@/g'
foo@bar@baz
```

Now I am trying to do the same thing using character class like this:

```sh
$ echo "foo}bar]baz" | sed 's/[}\]]/@/g'
foo}bar]baz
```

This did not work. I want to have a character class with two characters `}` and `]` so I thought escaping the square bracket like `}\]` would work but it did not.

What am I missing?

Comment: See [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Character-Classes-and-Bracket-Expressions) for full explanation.

Comment: Also, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35275040 might help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use "smart" placement:

```
echo "foo}bar]baz" | sed 's/[]}]/@/g'
```

See the [online `sed` demo](https://ideone.com/2JAU61)

Here, the `]` char must appear right after the open square bracket, otherwise, it is treated as the bracket expression close bracket and the bracket expression is closed prematurely.

Note that in case you want to safely use `-` inside a bracket expression, you may use it right before the close square bracket.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done in `bash` itself without calling any external utility like `awk` or `sed`:

```
s="foo}bar]baz"
echo "${s//[]\}]/@}"
```

```
foo@bar@baz
```

Another option is `tr`:

```
tr '[]}]' '@' <<< "$s"
```

```
foo@bar@baz
```